# Google Map don't load in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, appstore-approval, google-places

I’m using GoogleMaps pod in my iOS application and it was working fine, but in my last build, apple reject my application. And the reason behind that is, the map was unable to load at the time of review on iPad running iOS 12.2 on Wi-Fi.

I did try to reproduce that bug on my device but I couldn’t.

- Application do ask for location permission
- Google Place API key also seems ok.

Is there any way to identify what the actual issue is and how I am supposed to solve this one?

Comment: Did you try to reproduce the issue on same iOS version?

Comment: @PankajGaikar yes, I've tried to reproduce this issue on iPad with 12.2 OS (same version). But it's working fine at my end.

Comment: It may not be wise, but try to submit once again if you did not reproduce issue again. It might be a scenario specific problem in their review session.

Comment: @iOSDeveloper take video of iPad 12.2 version and give it link to the apple tester and resubmit app with video link.

Comment: @NiravKotecha Thanks but I've already resubmit my app with video link but after that they again report same issue.

Comment: @iOSDeveloper is your google map key is restricted ?

Comment: @NiravKotecha under Application restrictions, I've selected iOS apps and based on that I did provide bundle id of my app. and under API restrictions, I've selected Don't restrict key. But name of key is *iOS key (auto created by Google Service)*. Is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: @iOSDeveloper no issue. you have done correct things.

Comment: @NiravKotecha, thanks but issue is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've solved that issue and for that, I've done some of the changes in my project.

1 - I've patched the latest Google Plist file in the project (I wasn't sure whether the old one was latest or not)

2 - I was using multi language in my project so before setting the delegate of google map, I've set the language for my project.

3 - instead of set the google map from Storyboard, I've set the google map programmatically in my view controller after setting language.

After surfing for so long to solve this issue, I came to know that this issue occurs when your App supports multi language. These some steps did work for me.